# Import Error Bokeh show(), Cannot import name 'MACROS'

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, bokeh, importerror

**Using:** 
bokeh-0.13.0
python-3.6.3
jupyter notebook 5.0.0
Windows 10
Browser: Chrome

Anaconda:
anaconda custom py36h363777c_0
anaconda-client 1.6.14 py36_0
anaconda-navigator 1.8.7 py36_0
anaconda-project 0.8.0 py36h8b3bf89_0

im running the example tutorial form bokeh: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.10.0/docs/quickstart.html

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

# prepare some data
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [6, 7, 2, 4, 5]

# output to static HTML file
output_file("lines.html", title="line plot example")

# create a new plot with a title and axis labels
p = figure(title="simple line example", x_axis_label='x', y_axis_label='y')

# add a line renderer with legend and line thickness
p.line(x, y, legend="Temp.", line_width=2)

# show the results
show(p)
```

And i get this:

```
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\embed\util.py in ()
30 # Bokeh imports
31 from ..core.json_encoder import serialize_json
---> 32 from ..core.templates import _env, DOC_JS, FILE, MACROS, PLOT_DIV, SCRIPT_TAG
33 from ..document.document import DEFAULT_TITLE, Document
34 from ..model import Model, collect_models

ImportError: cannot import name 'MACROS'
```

haven't found something on google that helps me :/

Comment: This is almost certainly an installation problem on your specific system. `0.13.0` has been out for quite awhile, and there are many thousands of windows users, if there were a problem with the package itself we would have heard about it immediately. Have you tried uninstalling, perhaps manually blowing away everything Bokeh related in `site-packages`, and re-installing? Or alternatively, trying from a new freshly created conda env?

Comment: Unrelated, but please also note that the documentation link you are using is for version `0.10.0` which is *YEARS* out of date with respect to `0.13.0`

Comment: As a check, this is what the `bokeh.core.templates` file for `0.13.` looks like: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/0.13.0/bokeh/core/templates.py the the file your `site-packages` looks different than that (as it must) then your installation is corrupted or incomplete. Blow it away and start over.

Comment: I must admit that the solution was really dumb. I was lacking the jinja package, after installing it everything worked well.

Comment: That's weird I would expect an import error in that case. Glad it's working. It would be ideal if you can post this answer as an answer (or delete the question) so that if does not remain unanswered.

Answer (score -1):

After installing the jinja package via pip everything worked well.